# recyclerView doesn't display the images

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bitmap, display

I am trying to show images in recyclerView but it doesn't display the bitmaps.
I don't know what is wrong.

This is my adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final byte[] data = arrayList.get(position).getAsByteArray("byteArray");

    try {
        String tempImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/AHOORATempImage";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempImagePath);
        fileOutputStream.write(data);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(tempImagePath)));

        new File(tempImagePath).delete();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and This is the xml of my item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addContentGalleryImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a good idea to perform any calculations in `onBindViewHolder`, as this method should only *bind* views and ready items. Try to keep images in either memory (but be careful with OOM) or file and render it from the prepared images and not to delete it.

Comment: As well, are there any RecyclerView-related or file/images processing-related messages in logcat?

Comment: finally I found out that the problem is the byteArray because I have also used Glide but again no result. what is the reason that a byteArray can not be shown . can you please help ?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Picasso library](https://github.com/square/picasso) it's easy to use and very helpful with Url image especially.
here's an example to use in **onBindViewHolder**

```
Picasso.get()
            //Image url or path
            .load(channelImgUrl.get(position))
            //This line optional if you want a circle Image shape
            .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
            //Image View
            .into(holder.channelImg);
```

Comment: sorry , it didn't work. finally I found out that the problem is the byteArray because I have also used Glide but again no result. what is the reason that a byteArray can not be shown . can you please help ?? thanks.